# Semantic web - sparql query

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I'v tried this query, it compiled and run. but it retrieve just the column names without their values. how can I retrieve their values ? is there any special method for that ?

```
String str = "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"+
    "PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>"+
    "PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>"+
    "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>"+
    "SELECT DISTINCT ?label ?abstract ?placeOfBirth"+
        "?birthPlace ?birthDate ?deathDate ?page ?thumbnail WHERE {"+
        "OPTIONAL {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Neil_Simon> dbpprop:placeOfBirth ?placeOfBirth ; dbo:abstract ?abstract ; foaf:page ?page .}"+
        "OPTIONAL {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Neil_Simon> dbpprop:placeOfBirth ?placeOfBirth ; dbpprop:birthPlace ?birthPlace ;}"+
        "OPTIONAL {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Neil_Simon> dbpprop:placeOfBirth ?placeOfBirth ;  dbo:birthDate ?birthDate ;}"+
        "OPTIONAL {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Neil_Simon> dbpprop:placeOfBirth ?placeOfBirth ;  dbo:deathdate ?deathDate ;}"+
        "OPTIONAL {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Neil_Simon> dbpprop:placeOfBirth ?placeOfBirth ; dbo:thumbnail ?thumbnail .}"+
        "FILTER (LANG(?label) = 'en')"+    
        "FILTER (LANG(?abstract) = 'en')}"+
    "LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Note: There is no whitespace in your string between `?placeOfBirth` and `?birthPlace`

Comment: please, mark RobV's answer as correct (green tick), if it was helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get column names and no values then it likely means that there are no answers to your query.

Try removing parts of your query until you get an answer - the main parts to start with would be the `FILTER` clauses. You are filtering on variables that don't actually get bound in your query anywhere so they will always evaluate to false and result in no results

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was helpful.

Comment: If you found RobV's answer helpful, maybe you should mark the answer as correct.